Memory leak using pyobjc and Apple Vision VNRecognizeTextRequest
I'm using the Apple Vision library on a Mac to extract text from png images (about 10,000 images) using multiple processes with multiprocessing library in Python. But I found that the memory keeps increasing until out of control. So to simply the process and check memory closely, I tried it with a single image 3000 times and the same thing happens.
I'm using PyCharm on apple M1.
I've tried using NSAutoreleasePool but still no result.
import time
from Quartz import CIImage
from Vision import VNImageRequestHandler, VNRecognizeTextRequest
import multiprocessing
from Cocoa import NSURL, NSAutoreleasePool
import psutil
import os


def worker(job_queue):
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    while True:
        # Create an autorelease pool to manage memory
        pool = NSAutoreleasePool.alloc().init()

        try:
            t1 = time.time()
            job = job_queue.get()
            if job is None:  # Sentinel value to signal process to stop
                print(f"Worker {multiprocessing.current_process().name} exiting.")
                job_queue.task_done()
                memory_info = process.memory_info().rss
                print((multiprocessing.current_process().name, memory_info / 1024 / 1024))
                break
            print(f"Worker {multiprocessing.current_process().name} Job Number = {job[1]} url = {job[0]}")
            url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(job[0])
            ci_image = CIImage.imageWithContentsOfURL_(url)

            request = VNRecognizeTextRequest.alloc().init()
            handler = VNImageRequestHandler.alloc().initWithCIImage_options_(ci_image, None)
            success, error = handler.performRequests_error_([request], None)
            if error:
                print(f"Worker {multiprocessing.current_process().name} result = {success}, error = {error}")

            print(f"Worker {multiprocessing.current_process().name} done. Elapsed = {time.time() - t1}.")
            request = None
            handler = None
            # Get memory usage of the current process
            memory_info = process.memory_info().rss  # Resident Set Size in bytes

            print((multiprocessing.current_process().name, memory_info / 1024 / 1024))

        finally:
            # Ensure the autorelease pool is drained to release memory
            pool.drain()

        job_queue.task_done()

    memory_info = process.memory_info().rss
    print((multiprocessing.current_process().name, memory_info / 1024 / 1024))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a Queue for jobs
    job_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

    # Number of worker processes
    num_workers = 4

    # Create worker processes
    processes = []
    for i in range(num_workers):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(job_queue,result_queue), name=f"Worker-{i + 1}")
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    # Put jobs into the queue
    num_jobs = 3000
    for job_id in range(num_jobs):
        job_queue.put(["Path To File", job_id])

    # Add sentinel values (None) to signal workers to stop after jobs are done
    for _ in range(num_workers):
        job_queue.put(None)

    # Wait for all jobs in the queue to be processed
    job_queue.join()

    # Wait for all worker processes to finish
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print("All jobs completed.")



The program spawns 4 processes and loads 3000 jobs to a queue.
Each process takes a job from the queue runs text recognition on it, then marks it done and take another one.
I removed the part where it processes the text recognition because it is not relevant and memory still increases.
The memory consumption per process starts at about 250ish then finishes at around 340MB.
If I run this on more files, I would run out of memory.
How can I fix this?

Hello @Gyun, do you have an error message to show ?

@Lrx There's no error message as it runs fine. It's just that the memory consumption keeps increasing even though there is nothing being stored. Something's probably not getting released or there's a memory leak. That's what I'm trying to fix.

interesting. Did you check for any caching techniques used by the Apple Vision libraries ? there are usually harmless, and make a use of the memory to improve time efficiency

@Lrx I did but unfortunately couldn't find anything. As usual Apple's documentation  was not helpful and there was nothing on google.

Hey, I don't know if you're still concerned by this issue, but have you tried to use python tracemalloc library ? Maybe you could keep track of memory allocations during the executions of your script.
